# How to hide imported modules from namespace in iPython?

Tags: python

With this simple module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#file: foo.py
import ctypes

class Foo(ctypes.Structure):
   pass
```

In iPython:

```
In [1]: import foo
In [2]: foo.
Foo
ctypes
```

`ctypes` is a module used inside the module `foo`, it should not be shown to the user. The goal is to hide `ctypes` from the auto-completion offered by `ipython`

Is this solution too cumbersome?

```
import ctypes as __ctypes
```

Comment: I would say it's too cumbersome, yes (use a single underscore, at most). *Why* do you want to hide some of the names in your module's namespace? Have you considered using `__all__` (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/44834/3001761), if this is a concern for wildcard imports?

Comment: The user might get confused if it does not know that `ctypes` is a module used by my module, but not a feature of it. I am expecting the user to use the auto-completion to see what objects he can use. One solution is to create a static class inside the module where all the usable methods are located. I don't think it is a better solution

Comment: Why do you think anyone would be confused by that? There's no need for a static class, you could expose a list (just like `__all__`, and maybe even using that name!) of the names of attributes that are supposed to be used, but this happens whenever you have any imports and rarely proves to be a sticking point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python) for that. Your code would become something like:

```
import ctypes

# Note here
___all__ = []

class Foo(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

# Note here
__all__ += ['Foo']
```

If you do `from foo import *`, you'll see only `Foo` (or whatever else you add to `__all__`).

Comment: You don't need to add `'Foo'` at the end, I'd say it's neater to include all the names at the top of the file.

Comment: I agree it doesn't have to go after the class definition (after all, it's just a string), but I usually place it neither at the beginning nor at the end, but rather grouped with the class/function/whatever. This way, if I modify the definition, I remember to modify the all as well.

Comment: It does not work. If you `import` this module on iPython, the auto-completion will still show all the members of the module including `ctypes`.

Comment: @nowox See correction - it affects `from something import *`.